# Reading file line by line returns just the last line

Tags: c, arrays, file

This is incredibly strange - I'm getting the lines from a file, printing them out to the screen, and storing them in array.  When printing them out to the screen everything looks fine, but in the array every element is set to the last line of the file.

File looks like this:

```
DarkMatter
Fire
Water
Air
Earth
Plasma
Wind
```

This is my code:

```
char *rooms[7];
FILE *roomFile = fopen("rooms.txt", "r");
char name[20];
for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
    fgets(name, sizeof name, roomFile);
    rooms[i] = name;
    printf("%s", rooms[i]);
}
for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", rooms[i]);
}
```

When printing `rooms[i]` during the file loop everything looks fine, but once I try to print the rooms array afterwards, every element is set to `wind`.  How is this even possible?

Output:

```
DarkMatter
Fire
Water
Air
Earth
Plasma
Wind
Wind

Wind

Wind

Wind

Wind

Wind

Wind
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
rooms[i] = name;
```

with

```
//rooms[i] = name;
rooms[i] = malloc(20);
strcpy(rooms[i], name);
```

**Reason**

The statement `rooms[i] = name;` simply instructs that the pointer `rooms[i]` is equal to the pointer (or array) `name`. So effectively each of `rooms[0], rooms[1], rooms[2]` holds the address of `name`. In each iteration of your `for` loop, `name` gets copied with a different string. But the address pointed to by `name` and hence all the elements of `rooms` remain the same.

Comment: You fail to check for allocation errors. You also make no mention of the necessity to `free` allocations. It is bad to encourage such sloppiness in example code. It would be good to mention `strdup()` which is less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues to address here. You have declared `rooms` as an array of pointers to `char`, but then treat it as if it is a 2 dimensional array. You could `malloc` space to store strings, but it is simpler to simply declare `rooms` as a 2 dimensional array.

When you open a file, you should always check to be sure that the file opened successfully. If you choose to allocate memory, you should similarly check for allocation errors. You should also be checking the value returned by `fgets()` for errors.

In the first loop, you assign the contents of the buffer `name` to `rooms[i]`, which is a pointer. But you can't assign to arrays this way in C. If you change the declaration for `rooms` to:

```
char rooms[7][20]
```

then you can use `strcpy()` to copy the contents of `name` into `rooms[i]`. Alternatively you can use `strdup()` to duplicate the contents of the buffer. The advantage to this is that `strdup()` allocates storage for you, but you still must remember to free the memory later. You could also allocate the memory yourself, and copy the contents of `name` to the allocated region.

Here is a modified version of your code, using the simplest method, which is to simply declare `rooms` as a two-dimensional array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char rooms[7][20];
    FILE *roomFile = fopen("rooms.txt", "r");
    if (roomFile == NULL) {                     // error checking
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char name[20];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        fgets(name, sizeof name, roomFile);
        strcpy(rooms[i], name);
        printf("%s", rooms[i]);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", rooms[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```